# Farm GPS simulator

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, polygons

I'm trying to simulate a tractor (using a marker) that moves on a line and draws it's path behind it according to its width. I already made the tractor move on the line, the problem here is the path that it is supposed to be created behind it. I'm trying to figure out a way to create this path using just one polygon, by pushing coordinates into it (modifying the path value inside the polygon atributes).

This is an example path of a polygon that I'm using:

```
var auxPath = [{
  latitude: -28.226326,  
  longitude: -52.381693
},
{
  latitude: -28.223082,  
  longitude: -52.377215
},
{
  latitude: -28.223871, 
  longitude: -52.376465 
},
{
  latitude: -28.225963, 
  longitude: -52.378869
},
{
  latitude: -28.226254, 
  longitude: -52.379667 
},
{
  latitude: -28.227061, 
  longitude: -52.381127
}];
```

And this is my polygon:

```
$scope.tractorTrack = [
      {
        id: 1,
        path: auxPath,
        stroke: {
          color: '#000000',
          weight: 1,
        },
        editable: false,
        draggable: false,
        geodesic: false,
        visible: true,
        fill: {
          color: '#ffff4e',
          opacity: 0.7
        }
      }
    ];
```

I need to manipulate the coordinates inside the auxPath so it can follow the marker (the tractor) along the line.
I've made it work in a static way where I inserted the polygon coordinates manually, heres a print screen:
[image]

In this print, I'm just painting in two different directions, but I want a function that paint the map in all 4 directions.

By directions I mean this variations:

1. +latitude,+longitude;
2. +latitude,-longitude;
3. -latitude,+longitude;
4. -latitude,-longitude;

I've searched on the internet for this with no success... I hope I've been clear and made sense.